# Search pandas series for value and split series at that value

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, pandas

Python 3.3.3
Pandas 0.12.0

I have a single column .csv file with hundreds of float values separated by an arbitrary string (the string contains letters edit: *and will vary run to run*). I'm a pandas beginner, hoping to find a way to load that .csv file and split the float values into two columns at the level of that string.

I'm so stuck at the first part (searching for the string) that I haven't yet been able to work on the second, which I thought should be much easier.

So far, I've been trying to use `raw = pandas.read_csv('myfile.csv', squeeze=True)`, then something like `raw.str.findall('[a-z]')`, but I'm not having much luck. I'd really appreciate if someone could lend a hand. I'm planning to use this process on a number of similar .csv files, so I'd hope to find a fairly automated way of performing the task.

Example input.csv:

```
123.4932
239.348
912.098098989
49391.1093
....
This is a fake string that splits the data.
....
1323.4942
2445.34223
914432.4
495391.1093090
```

Desired eventual DataFrame:

```
Column A         Column B
123.4932         1323.4942
239.348          2445.34223
912.098098989    914432.4
49391.1093       495391.1093090
...              ...
```

Thanks again if you can point me in the right direction.

---

20131123
EDIT: Thank you for the responses thus far. Updated to reflect that the splitting string will not remain constant, hence my statement that I'd been trying to find a solution employing a regex `raw.str.findall('[a-z]')` instead of using `.contains`.

My solution at this point is to just read the .csv file and split with `re`, accumulate into lists, and load those into pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

raw = open('myfile.csv', 'r').read().split('\n')
df = pd.DataFrame()
keeper = []
counter = 0

# Iterate through the rows. Consecutive rows that can be made into float are accumulated.
for row in raw:
    try:
        keeper.append(float(row))
    except:
        if keeper:
            df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(keeper, columns = [counter] )], axis = 1)
            counter += 1            
        keeper = []

# Get the last column, assuming the file hasn't ended on a line
# that will trigger the exception in the above loop.
if keeper:
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(keeper, columns = [counter] )], axis = 1)

df.describe()
```

Thank you for any further suggestions.

20180729 EDIT2: One other possible solution using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import io
import itertools
import re

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

txt = """123.4932
239.348
912.098098989
49391.1093
This is a fake string that splits the data.
1323.4942
2445.34223
914432.4
495391.1093090
fake again
31323.4942
42445.34223
2914432.4
5495391.1093090
23423432""".splitlines()

groups = itertools.groupby(
        txt,
        key=lambda x: not re.match('^[\d.]+$', x)
)
df = pd.concat(
    (pd.Series(list(g)) for k, g in groups if not k),
    axis=1
)
print(df)
```

Comment: What is the delimiter, actually?

Comment: Unfortunately the lineterminator arg for read_csv doesn't let you do this (yet?) `ValueError: Only length-1 line terminators supported`

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, pandas still has trouble with data that is quite *that* unstructured. In cases like these, the solution involves a text editor or (more conveniently) Unix command line tools.

Comment: This would be yet another use case for my contiguous groupby [enhancement](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5494), although we can do this one without too much trouble without it.

Comment: The actual delimiter varies but will always be a sentence that starts with several words, possibly a few numbers and symbols. Should always fail a `.match('\d+')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `numpy.split()`:

```
import io
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

txt = """123.4932
239.348
912.098098989
49391.1093
This is a fake string that splits the data.
1323.4942
2445.34223
914432.4
495391.1093090
fake again
31323.4942
42445.34223
2914432.4
5495391.1093090
23423432"""

s = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(txt), header=None, squeeze=True)
mask = s.str.contains("fake")
pos = np.where(mask)[0]
pos -= np.arange(len(pos))

arrs = [s.reset_index(drop=True) for s in np.split(s[~mask], pos)]
pd.concat(arrs, axis=1, ignore_index=True).astype(float)
```

output:

```
               0               1                2
0       123.4932       1323.4942       31323.4942
1        239.348      2445.34223      42445.34223
2  912.098098989        914432.4        2914432.4
3     49391.1093  495391.1093090  5495391.1093090
4            NaN             NaN         23423432
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know you only have two columns, then you could do something like

```
>>> ser = pd.read_csv("colsplit.csv", header=None, squeeze=True)
>>> split_at = ser.str.contains("fake string that splits").idxmax()
>>> parts = [ser[:split_at], ser[split_at+1:]]
>>> parts = [part.reset_index(drop=True) for part in parts]
>>> df = pd.concat(parts, axis=1)
>>> df.columns = ["Column A", "Column B"]
>>> df
        Column A            Column B
0       123.4932                ....
1        239.348           1323.4942
2  912.098098989          2445.34223
3     49391.1093            914432.4
4           ....      495391.1093090
5            NaN  extra test element
```

If you have an arbitrary number of places to split at, then you can use a boolean Series/shift/cumsum/groupby pattern, but if you can get away without it, so much the better.

(PS: I'm sure there's a better way than `idxmax`, but for the life of me I can't remember the idiom to find the first True right now.  `split_at[split_at].index[0]` would do it, but I'm not sure that's much better.)